# Easy way to push data into MongoDB from Bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, mongodb

I know you can create a Javascript file that the MongoDB shell will execute upon startup.  But I'm hoping for something more "lightweight" than that.  I am using a Linux program that has a scripting language built in it.  But the scripting language can not do operations like opening sockets, etc.  It does have a "system" command to shell out to a Linux process.  I would like to be able to push data into MongoDB via a Bash shell script and immediately return to the Linux process that spawned it, and quickly if I can since I intend to do this a few times a second (but not much more than that).  It seems to me that shelling to the MongoDB shell and then have it execute a startup Javascript file would be a heavyweight operation relatively speaking?  Is there a command line that I could craft from a bash script that would do a few quick MongoDB database operations and the exit?  I have the MongoDB daemon running at all times on the default port.

Comment: this would be trivial in let's say python...

Comment: As well in perl.

Comment: calling system and a shell to run perl, python or another app is also relatively heavyweight